# Shared localization resource file in Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, localization

In .net 8 razor, how would I go about having a shared localization resource in my project?

Currently, I have the following layout:

[image]

This works for the index page, but I also want resources from RShared.resx (poorly named, but this is an example).

_ViewImports:

```
@using SE.Web
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@namespace SE.Web.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "LocalizationResources");

builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new CustomRouteModelConvention());
}).AddViewLocalization();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how would I go about having a shared localization resource in my
> project

Try to use the IStringLocalizerFactory interface to create IStringLocalizer instances, then register the Service with the DI system, below is a demo, you can refer to it.

1. Add a new class file to the Resources folder(your  LocalizationResources folder) named ***RSharedResources***. It is an empty class.

```
 public class RSharedResources
 {
 }
```

2.Add a new folder to the root of the project named Services. Add a C# class file to the folder named **RSharedService**.cs with the following code:

```
public class RSharedService
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer localizer;
    public RSharedService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
    {
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(RSharedResources).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
        localizer = factory.Create(nameof(RSharedResources), assemblyName.Name);
    }

    public string Get(string key)
    {
        return localizer[key];
    }
}
```

3.Register the RSharedService in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<RSharedService>();
```

4.Add a resource file to the Resources folder named RSharedResources.en.resx.

```
  Greeting      Hello afternoon!
```

5.Inject the RSharedService into the index page:

```
@using yourprojectname.Services
@inject RSharedService localizer
@localizer.Get("Greeting")
```

6. Pass the culture query parameter with the value set to de : `?culture=en`

Structure:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Got it - thanks!  Worked like a charm.   Was so hard to find an answer for this!

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer from Qing Guo, here was the final over-engineered version:

Services\LocalizerService

```
public class LocalizerService
{
    Dictionary<string, LocalizerResource> _localizedFactories = new Dictionary<string, LocalizerResource>();

    public IStringLocalizerFactory Factory { get; }

    public LocalizerService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
    {
        Factory = factory;
    }

    public LocalizerResource GetLocalizer<T>()
    {
        var res = new LocalizerResource(Factory, typeof(T));
        _localizedFactories.Add(nameof(T), res);

        return res;
    }

    public string GetValue(string resource, string key)
    {
        if (_localizedFactories.ContainsKey(resource))
            return _localizedFactories[resource][key];
        else
            return this[resource][key];
    }

    public LocalizerResource this[string resource]
    {
        get
        {
            if (_localizedFactories.ContainsKey(resource))
                return _localizedFactories[resource];
            else
            {
                var res = new LocalizerResource(Factory, resource);
                _localizedFactories.Add(resource, res);
                return res;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Resources\RSharedResources (same directory as shared resx file)

```
public class RSharedResources
{
}
```

Resources\LocalizerResource (same directory as shared resx files)

```
public class LocalizerResource
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IStringLocalizer Localizer { get; set; }
    public LocalizerResource(IStringLocalizerFactory factory, Type T)
    {

        var assembly = new AssemblyName(T.Assembly.FullName);
        Name = T.Name;
        Localizer = factory.Create(Name, assembly.Name);
    }

    public LocalizerResource(IStringLocalizerFactory factory, string name, string assemblyName = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(assemblyName)) assemblyName = this.GetType().Assembly.FullName;
        this.Localizer = factory.Create(name, assemblyName);
    }

    public string this[string key] => Localizer[key];
}
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LocalizerService>();
```

Potential uses in razor pages:

```
@inject LocalizerService sharedLocalizer
@{
//option 1: assign new variable to specific localizer
    var localizeTest = sharedLocalizer["RSharedResources"];
}
//and use it like this
@localizeTest["Greeting"]

//option 2: use the sharedLocalizer to specify both
@sharedLocalizer["RSharedResources"]["Greeting"]
```