Custom Resources global for multiple languages razor pages .NET 8
I am creating a multi-language application using Razor pages in .NET 8.0.
I want to use custom resource files for displaying multiple languages (such as WebUI.en-us.resx, WebUI.fr-fr.resx for display text in .cshtml and WebMessage.en-us.resx, WebMessage.fr-fr.resx for message response in server).
But currently .NET 8 is auto map the resource base on the views as shown below to get the resource for the page:

Does anyone have any efficient method or solution to use exactly some resource files that I want in Razor pages?
Thank you all!
My program.cs:
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Login");
})
    .AddMvcOptions(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                     .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                     .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI()
    .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
    .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

var app = builder.Build();

var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("fr") };

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});

I have try use ChatGPT for a solution shown here, but it still does not work.
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public class GlobalResources { }
    public class Global2Resources { }
    public class Global3Resources { }
}

@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@inject IStringLocalizer<YourNamespace.GlobalResources> Localizer1
@inject IStringLocalizer<YourNamespace.Global2Resources> Localizer2

<h1>@Localizer1["Test"]</h1>
<h2>@Localizer2["AnotherTest"]</h2>


I find a suitable solution in the topic below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77615351/shared-localization-resource-file-in-razor
